# Text on both side of vertical line

Tags: equations, vertical

I want text on both sides of a vertical line, that expands over several rows. Until now it worked for me using this code. But apparently that works only if the text with more than one row is on the right side. Now that I want to have several rows and the left side, latex doesn't make a new row, only a bigger spacing. What do I need to change to fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\[ 
 \text{Si + présent }  
  \left| \begin{array}{l}   
\text{+ présent}  \\
\text{+ futur}  \\
\text{+ impératif} \\
\text{+ conditionnel présent}
\end{array}\right.
\]
\end{fleqn}


\begin{fleqn}
\[ 
 \text{je } \\
 \text{tu}\\
  \text{il/elle/on}\\
   \text{ils/elles}
  \left| \begin{array}{l}   
 \text{boivent}
\end{array}\right.
\]
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `array` for line breaks, so you should swap things around to have

```
\[ 
\left.\begin{array}{l} 
 \text{je } \\
 \text{tu}\\
 \text{il/elle/on}\\
 \text{ils/elles}
\end{array}\right|
\text{boivent}
\]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a `tabular` which switches to text mode, so all the `\text` inside the `array` is not needed:

```
\[
\begin{tabular}{l|}
je \\
tu \\
il/elle/on \\
ils/elles
\end{tabular}\quad
\text{boivent}
\]
```

[image]

But do you need the math enviroments at all? What about something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, text={16.5cm, 25.2cm}, centering]{geometry}
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}


\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

Si + présent
\begin{tabular}{|l}
+ présent  \\
+ futur  \\
+ impératif \\
+ conditionnel présent
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{l|}
je \\
tu \\
il/elle/on \\
ils/elles
\end{tabular}
boivent

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you the \tabular version is so much easier... I didn't knew how to put the single word in the middle of the rows... so I used the complicated version in math mode but your version with tabular is much better.